# "No such file or directory" Error when doing simple fstream in c++ while using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I get the error "No such file or directory" when I run this at the top of my main:

Edit- This is my complete .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include "CommunicationNetwork.h"

using namespace std;

int DisplayMenu();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
ifstream file;
string data;
file.open("message.txt");

if(file.is_open()){
    cout << "WORKS" << endl;
}else {
    cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}

CommunicationNetwork network;

bool gbye = false;
while(gbye == false){

    int use = DisplayMenu();

    switch(use) {
        case 1:
        network.buildNetwork();
        break;
        case 2:
        network.printNetwork();
        break;
        case 3: 
        network.transmitMsg("message.txt");
        break;
        case 4: cout << "Add" << endl;
        break;
        case 5: 
        cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
        gbye = true;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I have used this method countless times to open txt files but this is the first time I am using a makefile with my program which I'm guessing is the cause of the problem.

Does "message.txt" need to appear in my makefile somewhere? Is so where? What if I want to pass the filename as a command line argument?

My makefile looks like:

```
PROG = com
CC = g++
OBJS = CommunicationNetwork.o Assignment.o
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)
CommunicationNetwork.o : CommunicationNetwork.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c CommunicationNetwork.cpp
Assignment.o :
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c Assignment.cpp
clean:
    $(RM) $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

The .txt file is saved in the same folder as my other files. I will get the error regardless of what .txt file I try. Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

Edit:

Both the .cpp and the .txt file are in the folder `Assignment`

for message.txt: `/Users/tannerquigley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/School/CSCI 2270/Assignment`

for Assignment.cpp: `/Users/tannerquigley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/School/CSCI 2270/Assignment`

in Terminal: `res1-131-132-dhcp:Assignment tannerquigley$ make` after I run a make clean

And then I open the "com" executable file that appears in the Assignment folder

Comment: Almost certainly this is unrelated to your makefile.  There's no need for the makefile to know what files your program intends to open.  Are you certain that you are executing `com` from the same directory where `message.txt` is located?  Can you post the complete code, the exact command you type to run your program, and a directory listing?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. The emphasis is on the "complete" part.

Comment: @NateEldredge Please check my edits. Minimal and Complete can be very contradictory but  I posted the rest of my .cpp

Comment: I am willing to place a substantial bet that the working directory in which your program is running is not the directory you _think_ it is.  If the file is in the same directory as the executable, try extracting the full path from the executable in `argv[0]` and either change the current directory to that, or prepend that path to "message.txt".

Comment: Maybe an OSX expert can tell us what working directory is used when you "open" an executable file (can you be more specific about how you "open" it?).  You can also call `getcwd` inside your program if you want to check what the working directory is.  I agree with @paddy that it probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @paddy @NateEldredge `argv[0]` returns `/Users/tannerquigley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/School/CSCI 2270/Assignment3/commun`. getcwd return "1" but I'm not exactly sure how to use it correctly. After I run `make clean` and `make` a unix executable file appears in my Assignment folder, I double click it opening a terminal window which runs my program.

Comment: @paddy What do you mean when you say "change the current directory to that"? What should I change and what to as I have yet to identify a different directory

Answer (score 0):

Do not run the Unix Executable File that appears in the Folder. Run the program from the same terminal window using the command `./com` or whatever you (I) named the program in the Makefile.